# Кассовые сборы с концерта

Tags: грамотная-речь

Можно ли употреблять понятие "Кассовые сборы" по отношению к выручке от продажи билетов на музыкальный концерт? Или это понятие используется только в театральном и киноискусстве?

Answer (score 2):

А почему нет? Толковый словарь Дмитриева,2003г.:

> ка́ссовый прил., употр. нечасто
>
> 1. Кассовой книгой называют книгу, где ведётся учёт операций, произведённых на специальном аппарате, пробивающем чеки.
> 2. Кассовым чеком называют билет с указанием стоимости товара.
> 3. **Кассовым сбором называют количество денег от продажи билетов на фильм, концерт и т. п. Большие кассовые сборы.** | Имя известного актёра
>    гарантирует фильму кассовый сбор.
> 4. Фильм называют кассовым, если он приносит хорошую прибыль от продажи билетов. Семь фильмов Стивена Спилберга входят в десятку самых
>    кассовых фильмов за всю историю кино.
> 5. Актёра, певца или модель в разговорной речи называют кассовыми, если они собирают большую аудиторию зрителей и приносят прибыль
>    устроителям их концертов, показов и т. п. Ширли Темпл было семь лет,
>    когда она стала самой кассовой актрисой.